# Replacement firefox plug-in for Copy as Plain Text

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, copy-paste

Using Firefox plug-ins I had a plug-in called Copy Plain Text v0.3.3 that stopped working with newer versions of Firefox several releases ago.

Does anyone have a replacement for this that works with the latest Firefox v10?

The plug-in adds a context sensitive menu to allow copying text from a web page with out any formatting, i.e. as plain text.  When I copy from a web page, I almost always just want the text and not any formatting, so this plug-in was a real big help.  Now I must paste into something like the search bar and copy a second time to strip the text of any formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current Mozilla plugin repository, there are several similar options that work with FireFox 10.x:

- [Copy As Plain Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-as-plain-text): Current version is 1.0.4
- [Copy Plain Text 2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-plain-text-2/): Current version is 1.0

Both plugins appear to offer the functionality that you're looking for.